# Very Simple Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Im using the Simple Slider but the jquery script doesnt work correctly..
see working here
http://morenamia.mx/slider/

The problem are in these line but i dont know where.

```
<i>
function moveLeft() {
    if($('#slider ul').position().left < (sliderUlWidth + slideWidth)){
     $('#slider ul').animate({
         left: - slideWidth
     }, 1000, function () {
         $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
         $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
     });
    }
};
function moveRight() {
    if($('#slider ul').position().left < (sliderUlWidth - slideWidth)){
     $('#slider ul').animate({
         left: + slideWidth
     }, 1000, function () {
         $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
         $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
     });
    }
};
</i>
```

the problem is when the image slides dissapear and make a strange effect, the right button works perfect but the left not.

anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: make a fiddle for that..

Answer (score 0):

It is just a guess, but if you're moving the slider one way you will prepend the image, the other way, you'll append the image. So you need to change one of these -

```
$('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
```

to this -

```
$('#slider ul li:last-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
```